# How to disable Dates in Android Material Calender

Tags: android

I'm using Material `CalendarView` and based `array` of dates `CalenderView` highlighting dates. So I want to disable the dates except Array of Dates.

```
 datePickerDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.getInstance());
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                    datePickerDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    datePickerDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    datePickerDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                    datePickerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.assignment_custom_datepicker);
                    materialCalendarView = (MaterialCalendarView) datePickerDialog.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
                  //  materialCalendarView.setShowOtherDates(MaterialCalendarView.SHOW_ALL);
                    materialCalendarView.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
                    materialCalendarView.invalidate();

                    materialCalendarView.setHeaderTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium);
                    materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance(R.drawable.background_solid_blue);
                    materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium);
                    materialCalendarView.setWeekDayTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Medium);
                    materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode(MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_SINGLE);

                  //  materialCalendarView.setWeekDayTextAppearance();
                    materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance(R.style.WalletFragmentDefaultButtonTextAppearance);
                    Calendar selectDayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    selectDayCalendar.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    materialCalendarView.addDecorators(
                            new OneDayDecorator()
                    );
                    if (calendarDays != null && !calendarDays.isEmpty() ) {
                        materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(Color.RED, calendarDays));
                        materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(this);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // materialCalendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(this);
                    }
                    if (readcalendarDays != null && !readcalendarDays.isEmpty()) {
                        materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new EventDecorator(Color.GREEN, readcalendarDays));

                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following :

```
ArrayList<CalendarDay> enabledDates = new ArrayList<>();

//Some for loop on dates{
    enabledDates.add(new CalendarDay(date));
}

materialCalendarView.addDecorator(calendarDecorator.new DayEnableDecorator(enabledDates));
```

The `DayEnableDecorator` is a separate class:

```
public class DayEnableDecorator implements DayViewDecorator{
    private HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

    public DayEnableDecorator(Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
        this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return dates.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setDaysDisabled(false);
    }
}
```

This would enable the dates that you put in the array `enabledDates` and disable the rest

Comment: Thank you, Ankur Aggarwal for the reply. For disabling dates is there any methods in material Calender. Actually enabled date based on ArrayList but for disabling dates facing problem.

Comment: @Ravi there is no separate decorator to disable dates. How `MaterialCalendarView` would work is that it will disable all dates automatically if they are not in the `enabledDates` list. I always use this and never face a problem

Comment: @Ravi Edited my answer. Now try this plz

Comment: But calendarDecorator is showing error. Is this build in method.

Comment: How to disable a particular dates

Answer (score 3):

Because for now, answer that provided by Ankur Aggarwal is not working - here is my solution.

Accepted answer will not work, because by default in MaterialCalendarView all days in enabled state.

First of all, we must disable **all** dates in `MaterialCalendarView`.

```
public class AllDaysDisabledDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            return true; //decorate all days in calendar
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            view.setDaysDisabled(true); //disable all days
        }
   }
```

And add this decorator to `MaterialCalendarView`:

```
materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new AllDaysDisabledDecorator());
```

After that, we must add another decorator, but for available and enabled dates (like in accepted answer):

```
public class AvailableDaysDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

        private final int color;
        private final HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

        AvailableDaysDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
            this.color = color;
            this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
            return dates.contains(day); //decorate only available days
        }

        @Override
        public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
            view.setDaysDisabled(false); ///important to enable day
            view.addSpan(new DotSpan(5, color)); //adds small dot to bottom of day number text
        }
    }
```

And add this second decorator:

```
materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new AvailableDaysDecorator(R.color.colorPrimary, days));
```

So, after this simple actions, you will get only needed days enabled and disabled all another days.